# I need to set “Envelope-From” header for wp_mail() in this plugin, but it's not working

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer

our wordpress site which is hosted on Hetzner sends out emails that go straight to spam, we've used a simple plugin on other sites which works but not on this site for some reason.

The plugin is simple, this is all that's in it:

```
            class email_return_path {
               function __construct() {
              add_action( 'phpmailer_init', array( $this, 'fix' ) );   
               }

            function fix( $phpmailer ) {
                $phpmailer->Sender = $phpmailer->From;
                }
            }

            new email_return_path();
```

The host says that the issue is because we don't have a valid "envelope-from" and "from" but how do I add this?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is only partly true: [`setFrom()`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L1235) only sets the sender in case the third argument is not set to false. Unfortunately, this is what the Wordpress built-in function [`wp_mail()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php?rev=47494#L170) is doing right now: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php?rev=47494#L358

In addition, Synchro is right, that the sender will automatically be set in case the e-mail would be sent through SMTP. However, this is not the case if the PHP `mail()` function is used (which I assume to be the Wordpress default), i.e., when PHPmailer uses the [`mailSend()`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L1762) function.

See https://www.webdezign.co.uk/avoid-wordpress-emails-ending-spam-folder/ or https://cobbledco.de/set-envelope-from-header-for-wp-mail/ how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is redundant - PHPMailer already does exactly this when [setting the from address using `setFrom()`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L1255), and [also handles it if `Sender` is not set when it sends an SMTP `MAIL FROM` command](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L1851).

So, beyond that you need to figure out exactly what is going astray; it's quite likely that the received message may contains headers that tell you what's wrong, so inspect them. [The PHPMailer deliverability guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Improving-delivery-rates,-avoiding-spam-filters) also contains useful advice on other causes.

One likely cause would be SPF failure; SPF applies specifically to the envelope sender address (rather than the From header), and if that's not permitted, you'll almost certainly end up in a spam folder or bounced altogether if your DMARC policy says so.